# Gravitational Waveform Plot From h5 File

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, hdf5

I want to plot a waveform from two black-hole mergersI have a .h5 file that I got from a public waveform catalog. I I am kind of a beginner with using python so I don't really know what to do in this situation. I have a .h5 file that has a .dat file inside that I want to use to make a plot. I got the file from a public waveform catalog at:

http://www.black-holes.org/waveforms/data/DisplayDownloadPage.php/?id=SXS:BBH:0001#

the name of the file is :

```
rhOverM_Asymptotic_GeometricUnits.h5
```

it is in the Lev5 directory. The contents of the .h5 file are described in:

https://www.black-holes.org/waveforms/docs.html

There is a dataset in the file that I think describes the waveform that I want to plot. The problem is that I don't know how to get into the data set. I have gotten as far as doing:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
from pylab import plot,show

f = h5.py.File("rhOverM_Asymptotic_GeometricUnits.h5","r")
ks = f.keys()
```

From here I don't know how to create the x and y axis that would go into the plot function. I am assuming that I need another attribute that belongs to the h5py module, but I am not even sure if I am using the right terminology. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py

f = h5py.File("rhOverM_Asymptotic_GeometricUnits.h5", "r")
data = f['Extrapolated_N2.dir/Y_l2_m-1.dat']
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], label='column1')
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 2], label='column2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to do this for days. Could you explain to me why you `data = f[....]`. How did you determine that was the data set? Also, from the graph, there seems to be two different sets of data on the it. What showed you that there was two different data sets?

Comment: Also, in `Extrapolated_N2.dir/Y_12_m-1.dat`, is there a directory that you where able to look into that showed the .dat file? If so, how would I be able to see it?

Comment: You can use the [hdfview](https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/) to view all contents in hdf file.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correct, first `f` was equated to the .h5 file, then the array `data` was made equal to the the `Y_12_m-1.dat` file inside of the `Extrapolated_N2.dir` directory, and then the elements of the array were made to equal columns of the array, then shown. Is that completely correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. "Extrapolated_N2.dir" is the Group and "Y_12_m-1.dat" is Dataset with shape (27338, 3).